# Stopping encryption on a MacOS ver.10.12 Time Machine

Tags: macos, encryption, data-recovery

I recently ran into a problem encrypting my external drive 1 TB My Passport for Mac as a Time Machine disk.  Its been locked at 97% completion for at least a week and can't seem to manage a TM backup.  I'd like to keep previous backups and read a previous post suggesting using this script in Terminal:

```
diskutil cs revert /Volumes/title_drive -passphrase
```

I enter /Volumes/My Passport for Mac -`Keychain password` but terminal  keeps returning this prompt:

> Convert a CoreStorage logical volume back to its native type. If you
>   are attempting to revert a disk on which conversion was started but
>   which could not be unmounted, you must eject the disk or reboot first.
>   The file system must be mounted and resizable (i.e. Journaled HFS+).
>   Ownership of the affected disk and a passphrase (if encrypted) is
>   required.

Not sure what I did wrong. I ejected the disk. The disk appears to be Journaled and mounted from this screenshot:

[image: Disk Utility]

Running "First Aid" does not return anything wrong with the disk.  I expect I have ownership for the disk as I'm the only user.
For reference a print-out when I run `diskutil cs list`:

```
> +-- Logical Volume Group 44B2E0C9-D1E6-400A-9EF5-996691A05F07
>     =========================================================
>     Name:         My Passport for Mac
>     Status:       Online
>     Size:         999826612224 B (999.8 GB)
>     Free Space:   0 B (0 B)
>     |
>     +-< Physical Volume B57FA8EB-6A1B-4537-B251-FFA027AC023F
>     |   ----------------------------------------------------
>     |   Index:    0
>     |   Disk:     disk2s2
>     |   Status:   Online
>     |   Size:     999826612224 B (999.8 GB)
>     |
>     +-> Logical Volume Family 87A99FC9-1BB7-47FC-B6ED-DFDEEF68FB87
>         ----------------------------------------------------------
>         Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
>         Encryption Status:       Unlocked
>         Conversion Status:       Converting (forward)
>         High Level Queries:      Not Fully Secure
>         |                        Passphrase Required
>         |                        Accepts New Users
>         |                        Has Visible Users
>         |                        Has Volume Key
>         |
>         +-> Logical Volume B2A532CB-0C9D-4474-992F-0591DD2F90DC
>             ---------------------------------------------------
>             Disk:                  disk3
>             Status:                Online
>             Size (Total):          999469088768 B (999.5 GB)
>             Conversion Progress:   97%
>             Revertible:            Yes (unlock and decryption required)
>             LV Name:               My Passport for Mac
>             Volume Name:           My Passport for Mac
>             Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to "escape" the spaces in your drive's name with backspaces, like this:

```
diskutil cs revert /Volumes/My\ Passport\ for\ Mac -passphrase
```

Use the flag "-passphrase" as written (you'll be prompted when to enter your actual passphrase).

Comment: Or just use quotes: `diskutil cs revert '/Volumes/My Passport for Mac' -passphrase`.