# How do I determine my title_drive?

Tags: macos, filevault

Okay so long story short, Filevault is trying to encrypt the hard drive. I don't want the process to continue (it is currently paused). I've searched and found solutions, however, they all mention the need for something called the `title_drive` and I have been unable to find what in the world that even stands for. I used both options for `diskutil list` and `ls -al /Volumes` and they both show very different things.

Just what *is* the `title_drive` exactly?

Running macOS Sierra 10.12.4 (in case this helps)

Comment: In this case, title_drive is a placeholder that you replace with the name of the volume being encrypted on your computer.

Comment: So in this case, it'd be /Volumes/Macintosh HD? I've tried it as that, and with a _HD or even with no space, and for all I get "unable to find disk for disk Volumes/whichever I tried using.

Comment: Enclosing the entire argument in single quotes is what you need. A space is not the same as an underscore, and to tell the computer the space does not mean the end of the argument you have to either enclose the entire path in single quotes, or use slashes before each space: https://superuser.com/a/1170141/74026

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

1. You need to find and use the name of the volume you wish not to encrypt.
2. Command line arguments cannot contain spaces because spaces usually mean that one argument is done and the next items in the line will contain a new argument.

To find the name of the volume use `ls -al /Volumes`. Get the name of the volume you need to run the command on and use that in place of `title_drive`.

If the name of the volume contains a space, you must enclose the entire argument in single-quotes:

> diskutil cs revert '/Volumes/My Volume Name Has Spaces'

Or, you need to use slashes preceding each space:

> diskutil cs revert /Volumes/My\ Volume\ Name\ Has\ Spaces -passphrase

Both these commands run `diskutil cs revert` with the `-passphrase` argument on a volume titled `My Volume Name Has Spaces`.

For more context, see these other two questions and their answers on MacOS Disk Encryption:

- [is there a way to stop mac osx disk encryption in progress?](https://superuser.com/questions/461757/is-there-a-way-to-stop-mac-osx-disk-encryption-in-progress)
- [Stopping encryption on a MacOS ver.10.12 Time Machine](https://superuser.com/questions/1130508/stopping-encryption-on-a-macos-ver-10-12-time-machine)